# PHP - Change file name from url when user downloads file

Tags: php

File links are all http://website.com/f/xxx.png/zip/txt and so on.
I need to set it up so that if a user downloads that file it would download with a different name.
I have seen how to do this on a normal page, but I have no clue how  making it work when the image itself is linked to is done.

Appreciate any help :)

Edit: Using the rewrite Steven Jeffries posted,

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $originalFileName . "'");
header("Content-Type:" . $mimeType);
$im = imagecreatefrompng($filePathOnServer);
imagepng($im);
```

to display images and

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $originalFileName . "'");
header("Content-Type:" . $mimeType);
```

to make other files download solved the issues I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an easy way to do this would be to redirect download links to another script that handles what to download, etc. Basically, I'd set up a download dir, add some rewrite rules, and then create a script to handle what gets output.

Something like this (untested):

/path-to-web-root/download/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.* /downloads/handle-downloads.php
```

/path-to-web-root/download/handle-downloads.php

```
$url = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

if (preg_match('^#downloads/(?<real_filename>.*?)/(?<options>.*)/(?<fake_filename>.*)$#', $url, $matches)) {
    // Double check my regex, but basically pull the real filename from the url here
    $actual_file = "/path-to-webroot/f/{$matches['real_filename']}";
    $options = explode('/', $matches['options']);
    if (in_array('zip', $options)) {
        // Handle zip, etc.
    }

    $fake_filename = $matches['fake_filename'];

    if (file_exists($actual_file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fake_filename).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actual_file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Then, instead of having the download link being website.com/f/xxx.png/zip/txt, you could instead do website.com/download/xxx.png/zip/txt/**new-filename.png**. This would allow you to set the filename to whatever you wanted since the browser will just take what's at the end of the url.

**Edit:** I've included the relevant code from [readfile's manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: This seems like something I could adapt to my case, thanks a lot.
I'll try it and mark as solved if it works first thing in the morning.

Comment: I am having issues displaying images with readfile, but your answer helped me answer the actual question, so thanks!              I am setting the mime stuff correctly, but the page still reads as the image data in text form, any helping clues here? :b

Comment: Yes, sorry, my example is very general and minimal. You'll still have to set the correct headers depending on the file, etc. You probably want to use the function `imagepng` instead of `readfile`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: Actually, upon looking at the manual, I don't think it matters, readfile will just output the bytes. I've updated my answer with the relevant code from readfile: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: So if I want to display an image without downloading by default and changing the filename if they save the image, would I have to "re-draw" the image first every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the file response file name by setting header parameter.

For example:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xyz.png"');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
...
```

More on PHP header function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php